# cannot ssh Docker Provided Container with Vagrant. Vagrant ssh doesnt work too

Tags: ssh, vagrant, docker, vagrantfile

I am fairly new to Vagrant and Docker both. 
What I am trying to do here is to get a container provided via docker in Vagrant and install a small webapp using the shell provisioner.

Here is my Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

# config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: 'echo Hi there !!!'

   config.vm.provider :docker do |d|
     d.name="appEnvironment"
     d.image = "phusion/baseimage"
     d.remains_running = true
     d.has_ssh = true
     d.cmd = ["/sbin/my_init","--enable-insecure-key"]
   end
end
```

The problem that i am facing here is that after the container is created it keeps running the following and eventually just stops. 
I can see a running docker container when i type in `docker ps` but it hasnt run the provisioning part. I am assuming it is because the ssh wasnt successful

```
==> default: Creating the container...
    default:   Name: appEnvironment
    default:  Image: phusion/baseimage
    default:    Cmd: /sbin/my_init --enable-insecure-key
    default: Volume: /home/devops/vagrantBoxForDemo:/vagrant
    default:   Port: 127.0.0.1:2222:22
    default:  
    default: Container created: 56a87b7cd10c22fe
==> default: Starting container...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 172.17.0.50:22
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
```

Can someone let me know where i might be wrong? I tried changing the image as well but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First download the insecure key provided by phusion from:

```
https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/insecure_key
```

*** Remember the insecure key should be used only for development purposes.**

Now, you need to enable ssh by adding the following into your Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage
RUN rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down
RUN /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh
RUN /usr/sbin/enable_insecure_key
```

Enable ssh and specify the key file in your Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "app" do |app|
    app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.build_dir = "."
      d.cmd = ["/sbin/my_init", "--enable-insecure-key"]
      d.has_ssh = true
    end 
  end
  config.ssh.username = "root"
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "path/to/your/insecure_key"
end
```

Up your environment

```
vagrant up
```

Now you should be able to access your container by ssh

```
vagrant ssh app
```

Comment: Cool, this works! Would you mind explaining a little about what's going on in those first docker lines? ... and do you have any advice on how to use my own generated keys?

Comment: phusion docker image by default disables ssh server.  In the dockerfile we enable it, removing /etc/service/sshd/down. The second line configures SSH server and the last one includes insecure key into /root/.ssh/authorized_keys. You can check the executed scripts at: https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh and https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/bin/enable_insecure_key.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this guide precisely, but in the end i still get `phusion: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The first thing that I can think is about your insecure_key file. Have you downloaded it and set the path at config.ssh.private_key_path = "path/to/your/insecure_key"? Is the file accessible by non root users?

Comment: I also keep getting
  app: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
I'm pretty sure the insecure_key file has the right permissions. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

`phusion/baseimage` does not have the insecure private key enabled by [default](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#enabling_the_insecure_key_permanently). You have to create your own base image `FROM phusion/baseimage` with the following:

```
RUN /usr/sbin/enable_insecure_key
```

Comment: I tried it with using the centos:7 or the Ubuntu:14.04 image too by running a ping command instead of enable insecure key. By default vagrant should use the default insecure keys shipped with vagrant and connect to the just provided container right? I don't see if this is related to the issue at hand right? Is that a correct assessment?

Comment: Docker containers by default **only** run one process. So if you use ubuntu or centos, you won't be able to ssh in unless you set the ssh daemon as the `ENTRYPOINT`. `phusion/baseimage` gets around this by setting up a complex entrypoint that runs other services using `runit`.